# How to stop all application servers in IBM WebSphere Application Server in linux?

Tags: websphere

I used this code to get list of server in WebSphere application server

```
servs = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Server,cell=my_name,node=mynode,*')
for server in servs:
    sname = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'name')
    print sname
```

It displays

```
server1
nodeagent
dmgr
```

I need to stop all application servers only, but it displaying

```
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3522E: No server by this name in the configuration:           WebSphere:name=dmgr,process=dmgr,platform=proxy,node=redhatmqCellManager01,j2eeType=J2EEServer,version=8.5.5.0,type=Server,mbeanIdentifier=cells/redhatmqCell01/nodes/redhatmqCellManager01/servers/dmgr/server.xml#Server_1,cell=redhatmqCell01,spec=1.0,processType=DeploymentManager
dmgr STARTED
```

I need to stop only all application servers in WebSphere application server.

Answer (score 1):

In your query string, you could exclude `processType=DeploymentManager` by explicitly specifying,

```
servs = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Server,cell=my_name,node=mynode,processType=ManagedProcess,*')
```

Comment: That excludes nodeagents too, which I think is what you want.